Evitar error de renderizado al dar al botón "atrás" del navegador tras la primera carga de la página
Estoy haciendo un sitio de administrador con React para una aplicación móvil. El proyecto compila y todo renderiza sin problemas, pero hay un bug importante que se da en la primera carga de la página: luego del inicio de sesión el usuario es redirigido a dashboard y la flecha del navegador para ir atrás está habilitada. Si se da click en ella en este punto, el navegador lanza el siguiente error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
at removeChildFromContainer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67430:19)
at commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78450:19)
at recursivelyTraverseDeletionEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78416:9)
at commitDeletionEffectsOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78527:13)
at commitDeletionEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78406:9)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78644:13)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78908:13)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78655:11)
at commitMutationEffectsOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78673:13)
at recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78655:11)

No es posible volver a la página mediante la flecha para ir adelante, pero se "arregla" para esa carga de la página tras la primera recarga; luego, aunque se vuelva a oprimir la flecha atrás el error no vuelve a ocurrir en la misma carga.
Intento arreglarlo mediante useNavigate y useLocation, de modo que, si se está en dashboard, se compruebe si es la primera carga de la página, en cuyo caso preferiría que se ignore la acción de la flecha atrás y/o se haga una recarga.
Dejo mi index.js donde intento manejar el error mediante la función useManageFirstLoad:
//* Imports generales
import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useNavigate,
  useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";

//* Mis imports
import Sidebar from "./Components/Sidebar/sidebar.jsx";
import RecetaDetalle from "./pages/Detalles/RecetaDetalle";
import Cuentas from "./pages/Cuentas/Cuentas.jsx";
import Recetas from "./pages/Recetas/Recetas.jsx";
import Categorias from "./pages/Categorias/Categorias.jsx";
import IngredientesPrinc from "./pages/IngredientesPrinc/IngredientesPrinc.jsx";
import Reportes from "./pages/Reportes/Reportes.jsx";
import Login from "./pages/Login/login.jsx";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";
import "./index.css";

const RedirectToDashboard = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigate("dashboard");
  }, [navigate]);
  return null;
};

//* Hook para manejar primera carga
const useManageFirstLoad = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === "/dashboard") {
      const handlePopState = (event) => {
        if (window.history.length <= 1) {
          event.preventDefault();
          navigate("dashboard");
        }
      };

      window.onpopstate = handlePopState;

      return () => {
        window.onpopstate = null;
      };
    }
  }, [location, navigate]);
};

const App = () => {
  useManageFirstLoad();

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="main p-3">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="cuentas" element={<Cuentas />} />
          <Route path="recetas" element={<Recetas />} />
          <Route path="categorias" element={<Categorias />} />
          <Route path="ingredientes-princ" element={<IngredientesPrinc />} />
          <Route path="reportes" element={<Reportes />} />
          <Route path="RecetaDetalle" element={<RecetaDetalle />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<RedirectToDashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>  
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/app/*" element={<App />} />
        /* *La sintaxis "/app/*" le indica a React * que app tiene rutas
        anidadas */
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

